# Can't re-enable BitLocker encryption on Windows 11 / Ubuntu 20.04 dual-boot laptop

Tags: bitlocker

I just bought a new laptop with Windows 11 pre-installed and it came with BitLocker storage encryption. I wanted to install Ubuntu OS on the same laptop as dualboot so I disabled the BitLocker and installed Ubuntu. Now I want to re-enable BitLocker encryption for security. However when I go to `settings > System  > BitLocker` I'm being taken to a screen where they ask me to pay 150 euro to update to Windows Pro to use BitLocker.

This is weird as I'm using Windows home and it already came with BitLocker. Do we have to update to Windows pro to use BitLocker? Is there any way to re-enable BitLocker for the windows partition without having to update to the Windows Pro version?

Comment: Windows Home does not contain Bitlocker, only the "device encryption" feature which is very close to Bitlocker and only works on certain new computers.

Comment: “BitLocker. Do we have to update to Windows pro to use BitLocker?” - Yes

Comment: Hi, thank you for the response. Can you please tell me how to re-enable this device encryption?